# How to print just the value in <QuerySet [{'...': '...'}]>

Tags: python, django

I want to print just the second value in Queryset.

print(DataSheet.objects.filter(id=i).values('Gênero'))

output:

```
<QuerySet [{'Gênero': 'Dichotomius'}]>
<QuerySet [{'Gênero': 'Dichotomius'}]>
<QuerySet [{'Gênero': 'Dichotomius'}]>
<QuerySet [{'Gênero': 'Dichotomius'}]>
```

expected output:

```
Dichotomius
Dichotomius
Dichotomius
Dichotomius
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataSheet.objects.filter(id=i).values_list('Gênero', flat=True)
```

or you can also convert it into list

```
list(DataSheet.objects.filter(id=i).values_list('Gênero', flat=True))
```

Comment: Ok, but the output was: "<QuerySet ['Canthidium']>." What I mean is that the expect output shoud be just "Canthidium". Is it possible?

Comment: I guess you are using a loop to print.. right...??

Comment: yes.. i want to show all rows of a database column and i also want to store these values in variables... so i want to capture them that way

Comment: `list(DataSheet.objects.all().values_list('Gênero', flat=True))`... if you want to get all the values you can use `objects.all()` and you will get values in a list as mentioned in the solution.

Comment: or else considering id will be unique... and you want to use loop then `DataSheet.objects.filter(id=i).values_list('Gênero', flat=True)[0]` will work...

Answer (score 1):

You should use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) in this case.

```
print(DataSheet.objects.filter(id=i).values_list('Gênero', flat=True))
```

> This is similar to values() except that instead of returning dictionaries, it returns tuples when iterated over.
>
> If flat=True, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples.

Comment: Ok, but the output was: "<QuerySet ['Canthidium']>." What I mean is that the expect output shoud be just "Canthidium". Is it possible?